# RedirectMatch Rules ::::: resume rules

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect many blog posts from an URL to another (remove .html and number_ in the beginning):

`https://www.test.com/blog/post/12_post_name.html` 
TO
`https://shop.test.com/post_name/`

I need 1 rule for all posts, I tried:

```
RedirectMatch 301 "^/blog/post/12_*(.*)\.html$" "https://shop.test.com/$1/"
```

It works for "12_" only (I need from 12 to 59)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is incorrect as it explicitly states `12` and does not use a `*` quantifier. It should be

`^/blog/post/((1[2-9])|([2-5][1-9]))_(.*).html$`

Alternatively, if you don't want to limit to that specific range, you could replace the `((1[2-9])|([2-5][1-9]))` with a more generic `[0-9]+`

Comment: Yes I know, when I explicitly state 12 it works fine for one post but when I changed it with the range the redirection becomes wrong
I tried this rule: `RedirectMatch 301 "^/blog/post/((1[2-9])|([2-5][1-9]))_*(.*).html$" "shop.test.com/$1"` When typing: test.com/blog/post/40_blog_name.html I get: shop.test.com/40 and I need to get: shop.test.com/blog_name

Comment: The `$1` refers to the first group. If you use the regex with the range you will probably need to use `$3` to refer to the third group, i.e. `(.*)`.

Comment: Not working, I tried:
`RedirectMatch 301 "^/blog/post/((1[2-9])|([2-5][1-9]))_*(.*).html$" "shop.test.com/$2"`
and
`RedirectMatch 301 "^/blog/post/((1[2-9])|([2-5][1-9]))_*(.*).html$" "shop.test.com/$3"`

The working solution still:
`RedirectMatch 301 "^/us/blog/post/12_*(.*)\.html$" "https://shop.olivafix.com/$1/"
...

RedirectMatch 301 "^/us/blog/post/59_*(.*)\.html$" "https://shop.olivafix.com/$1/"`
I wanted to replace those 47 rules by one rule.
Sample post link: https://olivafix.com/us/blog/post/12_how-to-take-good-care-of-your-dentures-while-traveling.html

Comment: What is the outcome when you use `$3`? Does it still redirect to `/40` (as an example).